# MDADM says can't assemble RAID5 because missing disks but all disks are there

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, raid-5

To start this, I installed a SATA expansion card so I could get more Drives into the computer. I moved the RAID to the expansion card, after attempts failed to get the OS SSD onto them. There was a failure (Should of figured there would be problems if couldn't read SSD), but the disks don't seem damaged in anyway.

Now When i try to assemble my RAID5 it gives me:

```
19:31 ~ ->sudo  mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/0 assembled from 2 drives - not enough to start the array.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

After examination each drive of the array and I get two drives with this:

```
 Device Role : Active device 5
 Array State : ...A.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

And the other four with this:

```
  Device Role : Active device 0
  Array State : AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Other than that, they all say Checksum is correct and State is clean. But the Events are different 824984 for the four that say all is ok and 825000 for the two.

The disks look fine, it just that 2 of the disks think that 4 other disks are missing. Is there a way to inform they are not?

Example of one the examinations:

```
        Magic : a92b4efc
      Version : 1.1
  Feature Map : 0x1
   Array UUID : ebc27588:efcd239d:3f714464:28982c31
         Name : localhost.localdomain:0  (local to host localhost.localdomain)
Creation Time : Sun Apr 25 04:23:29 2010
   Raid Level : raid5
 Raid Devices : 6

Avail Dev Size : 1953521400 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Array Size : 4883803200 (4657.56 GiB 5001.01 GB)
 Used Dev Size : 1953521280 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
   Data Offset : 264 sectors
  Super Offset : 0 sectors
  Unused Space : before=192 sectors, after=120 sectors
         State : clean
   Device UUID : 66d4c996:ab623ab2:0d2905e3:23fb1b28

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Nov 11 18:33:47 2014
       Checksum : 530097d6 - correct
         Events : 825000

        Layout : left-symmetric
    Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : ...A.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Comment: Are the magic numbers the same for each drive in examine?

Comment: Yes they are, nothing seems wrong except that 2 of the disk seem to think that the other 4 are missing

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue.

I ran a two times:

```
20:30 ~ ->sudo mdadm --assemble --force --verbose /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh /dev/sdi1
```

After the second time is started up the RAID with one disk missing. Disk is in the process of recovery now. Should be able to use the array like before!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the right time to ask for your backup strategy.
Eventually use the `--force` on mdadm `--assemble`.
Read https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery on the topic,  and if you have to `--create` again,  it's time to have a backup or a good prayer at hand.